# how do i remove numbering before each output prediction value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, printing, prediction

I am a beginner of python and I met a question regarding prediction output.

I tried to predict test data 'P1TestingData' in ComplexModel and write it to a CSV file. However, when I print 'prediction' which contains my prediction data out, it shows that there is a numbering starting from 0 before each of my data. How do I remove those numbering?
I tried to write it to CSV file but the numberings are still there

Input:

ComplexModel.params

```
P1TestingData = pd.read_csv('P1TestingData.csv', header=0)

prediction = ComplexModel.predict(P1TestingData) 

print(prediction)

f = open("abc.csv", "w")

f.write(str(prediction))   

f.close()
```

Output:

```
0       53.030011

1       -4.019369

2       14.452136

3        3.773111

4       14.535092

5       42.755951

6        6.566402

7       -0.399492

8       32.981286

9       21.616334

10      27.053343

11      20.591277

12      42.253588

13       9.253549

14       5.583377

15       8.145914

16      13.759630

17      -0.371573

18       5.036368

19      -0.338478

20      65.272560
```

Comment: Yes, because you are just *dumping the string representation of your pandas object to a file* and calling it a csv. That doesn't magically make it adhere to the standardized format. Rather, use `prediction.to_csv('abc.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `str(prediction)` is giving you a string like that:
`"0 53.030011 \n 1 -4.019369 ..."`
Therefore you can split your string with the function `split`.

For exemple, if you wanna split the string to have each line in a array you can do this : `str(prediction).split("\n")`.
This will give you an array like that : `["0 53.030011", "1 -4.019369", ...]`

Then you want to have only the second number. Same thing, you want to split the string but this time with the space character as your separator.

The final code should looks like this:

```
prediction_str = str(prediction)
lines = prediction_str.split("\n")
numbers = [line.split(" ")[-1] for line in lines]
print(numbers)
```

The third line is a bit complicated. What it said is you want to create a new array, for each element in lines. For each line, you split the string into another array with the space character as the separator. "1 -4.019369" becomes [1, -4.019369]. Taking the last item (with [-1]) will get your number.

EDIT: I am not really aware how csv file are working. This is a workaround in your situation, if you cannot gather your numbers in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate index column of `Pandas` by setting `index=False`.

CSV output:

```
prediction.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Print:

```
print(prediction.to_string(index=False))
```